# I would like to create 'second', 'third' (perhaps up to 'ninth') custom methods for ActiveRecord and maybe push (contribute) the changes to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, open-source, customization

I've never submitted anything to an open source project, and frankly, don't care what the rails people think about the methods. I love the 'last' and 'first' methods and would like to extend that concept into the methods 'second'-'ninth' for the purposes of sampling.

How might I create my own custom method that would graft these methods onto ActiveRecord?

**Currently watching Ryan Bates's screencast #50 at railscasts.com

** brainstorming on how to implement this, I'm thinking it could loop over the :id values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4...) until it finds the next record. And then the 'third' command could skip past the first match until it finds the second match (Model.third), and so on. Ha now I'm wondering if .first uses this same method. I suppose I'll check out the source code. :)

** As I venture down this road I'll be leaving a list of relevant links (I can't list more than 2 links unless I get 10 points. give me a one-up so I can add more)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/50-contributing-to-rails

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a bit more complex than you might think, because `first` and `last` are not individual methods on individual classes, but they are implemented on many different classes in ActiveRecord.

For example,

- You can use `Post.first`, in which case you are calling `ActiveRecord::Base#first`.
- You can use `Post.where(:submitted => true).first`, in which case you are calling `ActiveRecord::Relation#first`
- You can use `Post.comments.first`, in which case you are calling `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation#first`

See where this is going? In order to have similar behavior for `second`, `third`, and so on, you need to implement these methods in several places, not just one.

But just to get you started, here's how you could implement `ActiveRecord::Relation#second`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def second
    if loaded?
      @records[1]
    else
      @second ||= limit(2).to_a[1]
    end
  end
end
```

Execute this piece of code in an initializer, for example, and all of a sudden you call `second` on all relations.

Comment: What would I label that file? active_record.rb?

Comment: I would agree this monkey patching method is ideal.  I have a whole slew of modifications I make to core classes I do in a very similar way.  if you really want to share your work why not post this as a gem and if enough people like it you would probably have a better justification to spend the time to make a rails core pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't count your luck on getting something committed into rails core if your attitude is "frankly, don't care what the rails people think about the methods", however in saying that any one is welcome to pull the source from github and make their own modifications.

Likewise you are free to submit "pull requests" back to the rails team, to get you changes committed back into rails, however whether or not they are merged back into rails is decided by the maintainers of rails.

To get started Clone the project on github, make the changes yourself and then submit a pull request. There is clear instructions here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html (see section 5 in particular)

Comment: Well I do care what they think, obviously, but don't plan on letting that stop me that's all I'm saying

Comment: Ok Great - Remember you can also keep your own branch on github with your own modifications and point your Gemfile to your own branch too.

Comment: Which rails version should I be looking at?

Comment: master? is master where the "rails 4" changes are being made?

Comment: You wouldn't want to fork and maintain your own copy just for this, you could just make it a gem and put it in a Railtie.